# What are the legal restrictions, if any, on someone skydiving from a homemade rocket?

Tags: law

Consider the hypothetical situation in which someone builds a rocket, launches in it, ejects at max altitude and skydives to the ground. The maximum rocket height would be between 5,000 and 14,000 feet. The launch would take place somewhere deserted and flat (i.e. the Black Rock Desert).

Besides permission from the landowner, would such a launch require any sort of legal permission? Would the FAA or some other governing body need to sign off on it? Additionally, this is a bit far fetched to ask, but would the bureau of land management likely allow someone to perform such a launch on public land?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because skydiving from a homemade rocket is not related to space exploration.

Comment: @OrganicMarble We do have a Sounding rockets tag...

Comment: Hypothetical stunts have little to do with sounding rockets.

Comment: @OrganicMarble happy to take this down if it's not appropriate. Just looking for some legal advice.

Comment: @JSMorgan legal advice is off topic here, but not on all Stack Exchange sites. There is a law SE, I believe.